# Jquery If and else statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Im trying to create a if statement in jquery but i cant get it to work i have made a  [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uk67u/2/)

also code

HTML:

```
<div class="playlist-player shrink"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
if($('.playlist-player').hasClass('shrink')) {
    $(".playlist-player").mousedown(function(){
        $(".playlist-player").addClass("enlarge").removeClass("shrink");
    });
} else {
    $(".playlist-player").mousedown(function(){
        $(".playlist-player").addClass("shrink").removeClass("enlarge");
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
.shrink {background-color:red;}
.enlarge {background-color:blue;}
.playlist-player {height:20px; width:20px;}
```

Comment: you seem to be messing up css and javascript, or maybe you should add `style` and `script` tags appropriately

Comment: You are checking if the element has the class `shrink` once, when the page loads.  Then you are assigning a click handler, once.  You probably want to assign the handler, then check `hasClass` *inside* the handler.

Comment: The code appears to do what it attempts to do.  When I click on the element in the jsfiddle, it replaces the `shrink` class with the `enlarge` class as expected.  In what way is it not working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `if` `else` `addClass` `removeClass` You can do that with `toggleClass()` -

```
$(".playlist-player").mousedown(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("enlarge").toggleClass("shrink");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/Uk67u/8/

Comment: You can even chain it: `$(this).toggleClass('enlarge').toggleClass('shrink');`

Comment: @BrendanBullen Even better: `$(this).toggleClass("enlarge shrink")`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(".playlist-player").mousedown(function(){
    if ($('.playlist-player').hasClass('shrink')) {
        $(".playlist-player").addClass("enlarge").removeClass("shrink");}
    else {        
        $(".playlist-player").addClass("shrink").removeClass("enlarge");}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".playlist-player").mousedown(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("shrink")){
        $(this).addClass("enlarge").removeClass("shrink");
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("shrink").removeClass("enlarge");
    }
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/Uk67u/4/

Answer (score 1):

Might I encourage you to greatly simplify your code:

```
<div class="playlist-player shrink"></div>

<style type="text/css">
    .playlist-player {height:20px; width:20px;background-color:red;}
    .enlarge {background-color:blue;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.playlist-player').click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('enlarge');
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uk67u/6/)

- You will want your css and js in style and script tags.
- You can have a default style of background-color:red that can be overwritten with another class (enlarge) - *don't forget that your overriding class needs to be after the default class in the css*
- You can use toggleClass instead of an if/then statement
- Don't forget to wrap your handler in a `$(document).ready` (or `$(` in my code) to ensure that the `div` has loaded when you try to attach the handler
- if you want the user to perform a full click before triggering the handler (which is usual behavior for buttons), use the `click` handler (if not, you can replace `click` in my example with `mousedown`

Comment: I see you're separating out your code. You can ignore the first point about script/style tags

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking if it has the class once, you want to check after each click:

```
$('.playlist-player').mousedown(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('shrink')
        $(".playlist-player").addClass("enlarge").removeClass("shrink");
    else 
        $(".playlist-player").addClass("shrink").removeClass("enlarge");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".playlist-player").mousedown(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("enlarge shrink");

    // You can also check the console for class
    console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uk67u/9/)

Comment: +1 His code is not the prettiest, but it does work as the OP desired.

Comment: @PalashMondal I guess people didn't realise you can toggle multiple classes in one go. +1 for the right answer anyway